# Attach eclipse to a running install4j installer

Tags: java, eclipse, install4j

I'm just beginning with Install4j and I have some custom code which I need to step through and debug. Is there a way to attach eclipse to a running installer and have it break inside my code?

Comment: Google execute command line eclipse. You want to run your program from within eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Testing and debugging](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/) section in the documentation:

You can set up the installer or the uninstaller in your IDE by

- setting the working directory to the debug directory
- including your own code in the class path
- including i4jruntime.jar in the class path
- including user.jar in the class path. Your own code will also be contained in user.jar, but the IDE typically places project code at the beginning of the class path so it will override equivalent classes in user.jar.
- using the main class com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer for the installer or com.install4j.runtime.installer.Uninstaller for the uninstaller
- passing the VM parameter -Dinstall4j.debug=true

Note: The working directory for the executed java process must be the debug directory, otherwise both the installer as well as the uninstaller will not work.